# how can i return complete object in drop down list from angular 2 to the service?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

how can i return object form drop down list to the service ?

i want when ever i clicked on item in onChangeForComponent can get component object

```
  <select [ngModel]="selectedDev" (ngModelChange)="onChangeForComponent($event)" name="sel3" >
  <option *ngFor="let component of  Component "  [value]="component"   >
{{component.name}}
</option>
```

and use it as

```
selectedDev:comp;
onChangeForComponent(value){

this.selectedDev=value;
alert(this.selectedDev.name);

   this.componentCollection.push({

"id": this.selectedDev.id,
"name": this.selectedDev.name,
"description": this.selectedDev.description,
"nrc": this.selectedDev.nrc,
"mrc": this.selectedDev.mrc,



});
```

Comment: what is the question

Comment: how can i return object form drop down list to the service  on change method?

Comment: where is the service?

Comment: i mean change Method  onChangeForComponent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a model variable , you can just do this,

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedDev" (ngModelChange)="onChangeForComponent($event)" name="sel3">
  <option *ngFor="let component of  Component " [value]="component.name">
    {{component.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In **`typescript`**

```
onChangeForComponent(value){
 let componentselected = this.Component.filter(t=>t.name ==value);
 this.componentCollection.push(componentselected );
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hIGvSfVRxOLCOGkaQW1c?p=preview)**

Comment: you mean the selectedDev?

Comment: yeah i mean value and selectedDev

Comment: actually your answer helps me but you can add  because i selected one not array this.componentCollection.push(componentselected [0]);

Comment: add what ?i dont get

Comment: parameter of push is an object not array because  componentselected  can return array of same name by the way . i did it by id and take the first element

Comment: still i am not sure about your problem

Comment: Actually i tried to do this from first but i have not 15  reputation  to do this can you mark question is good to take more reputation i have now 13 :D